# how to avoid shell=True in subprocess

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, popen

I have subprocess command to check md5 checksum as

```
subprocess.check_output('md5 Downloads/test.txt', stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

It works fine.
But I read try to avoid `shell=True`
but when I run

```
subprocess.check_output('md5 Downloads/test.txt', stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=False)
```

I get error `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Can I run above command or workaround with `shell=False` or it's ok to keep `shell=True`?

Comment: Maybe for background see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/874188

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just pass the arguments to `check_output()` as a *list*:

```
subprocess.check_output(["md5", "Downloads/test.txt"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> *args* is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence
>   of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally
>   preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required
>   escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file
>   names). If passing a single string, either *shell* must be `True` (see
>   below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed
>   without specifying any arguments.

Answer (score 4):

in case of complex commands , you can use shlex to pass the commands as a list  to Check_Output or any other subprocess classes

from the document

shlex.split() can be useful when determining the correct tokenization for args, especially in complex cases:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

coming to above example

```
import shlex
inp="md5 Downloads/test.txt"
command=shlex.split(inp)
subprocess.check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```