# How to avoid using Shell=True

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

My script doesn't want to start.
If I run the command `localsite = subprocess.Popen("Localsite.py")` it returns `OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`.

To fix that I can use `localsite = subprocess.Popen("Localsite.py", shell=True)` which I'm not actually completely sure what it does. But I could imagine that it would cause issues as the software is going to be distributed and used by regular users without having Python installed.

But how can I avoid using `shell=True`?

Comment: good answer about `shell=True` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess

Comment: shouldnt it be `subprocess.Popen(["python", "Localsite.py"])` ?

Comment: `subprocess.Popen(["python", "Localsite.py"])` doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: maybe will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651990/oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application

Comment: It didn't, he said that Python has to be available in the path which is exactly what I'm having a problem with as this is going to get distributed. The other 2 answers use `shell=True`

Comment: You should als consider just to import the `Localsite.py` script.

Comment: I could see why that would be easier. But I'd rather make it as easy on the computer as possible. Using `subprocess` I would also be able to end the process. As far as I've understood using a module is code blocking. Which won't work for my current project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to avoid shell=True in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100820/how-to-avoid-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Answer (score 0):

You should make it

```
localsite = subprocess.Popen(["<Path to python exe>", "Localsite.py" ])
```

instead of

```
localsite = subprocess.Popen("Localsite.py")
```

You need to specify which python.exe to be executed and what are the arguments to that python.exe

Comment: Would there be another way to do this as I'm distributing this to users without Python? I'm using PyInstaller to create and executable but how would I call "Localsite.py"?

Comment: For this particular problem you may find the doc helpful
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/operating-mode.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with the entry point thing and I have looked at the docs. But I can't find out how to call Python when it has been bundled together to a folder. I'm using the regular bundling method for my Python scripts so that everything gets added into a folder. But I can't find any Python.exe file in there.